# Don't working explode() in PHP

Tags: php

There is a HTML file.(source of http://stackoverflow.com)

```
<html><head>
<title>Stack Overflow</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico
?v=6cd6089ee7f6"> ... blablabla
```

I want to divide the html file based on

```
<title>Stack Overflow</title>
```

So, I did like this :

```
$rex = explode("<title>Stack Overflow</title>",htmlspecialchars($html));
echo $rex[0];
```

What I expected :

```
<html><head>
```

but the result is nothing. When I delete

```
<title></title> tags
```

The result is shown well.

```
<html><head><title>
```

but It's not I want to.
How to divide string based on html tags?

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars()`? That function is for _output escaping_. By using it with `explode()`, you are modifying the input such that it no longer matches your delimiter.

Comment: If you run this without `htmlspecialchars()`, it should work more or less. But there may be other stuff (like blank lines) in the HTML source before the opening `<head>`, so your `<html><head>` may not be in the `$rex[0]` position.  There are certainly easier or more appropriate ways to parse HTML with PHP though, like DOMDocument.

Comment: have you tried preg_match_all() ?

Answer (score 0):

`explode` is useful for removing delimiters from concatentated strings, not for parsing through an entire document with different "delimeters", such as `<title>`, `<head>`, etc.

Example of `explode()`:

```
<?php

$array = explode(':', 'string1:string2:string3');
var_dump($array);

?>
```

Output would be something along the lines of:

```
array{[0] => 'string1', [1] => 'string2', [2] => 'string3'}
```

That's not exact output, but you get the idea.

What you could probably do is use `file()` to load each line of the HTML document into an array, then use a `foreach()` loop to `explode()` each line at a specific delimiter, and `break` when you find the string you want.